# spring data findById() works with curl but not with browser

Tags: java, spring, curl

I have a music mysql-database and I'm trying access it with spring data.
I, so far, have three methods in my controller-class: 
`getAlbumById`, `getAllAlbums` and `getAllArtists`. The last two works well with `curl 'localhost:8080/demo/allAlbums'` and `curl 'localhost:8080/demo/allArtists'`. curl is returning all albums and all artists. 
The methods also work if I use the Firefox-browser. With `curl 'localhost:8080/demo/oneAlbum/{1}'` I get the result: `{"present":true}` for id 1 to 16(I have inserted 16 albums). For id 17 I get the result: `{"present":false}` so this seems to work.  However, when I put `'localhost:8080/demo/oneAlbum/{1}'` in the Firefox browser I get this message:

`Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Sat Jan 20 11:08:48 CET 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
For input string: "{1}"`

Can someone explain why this is happening?

And also, one thing I find strange is that, if I change the `@PathVariable` of `getAlbumById` from String to Integer, the call with curl is still working but I get a different message in the browser:

`Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Sat Jan 20 11:38:18 CET 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{1}"`

Why is the call with curl still working?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path="/demo") 
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    private AlbumRepository  mAlbumRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ArtistRepository  mArtistRepository;

    @GetMapping(path="/oneAlbum/{id}")
//  public @ResponseBody Optional<Album> getAlbumById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Integer id) {  
    public @ResponseBody Optional<Album> getAlbumById(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id) { 

        Integer i = Integer.parseInt(id);
        return mAlbumRepository.findById(i);
    }

    @GetMapping(path="/allAlbums")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<Album> getAllAlbums() {
        return mAlbumRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping(path="/allArtists")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<Artist> getAllArtists() {
        return mArtistRepository.findAll();
    }    
}


@NoRepositoryBean
public interface ReadOnlyRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends Repository<T, ID> {
       Iterable<T> findAll();
       Optional<T> findById(ID id);
}


@Repository
public interface AlbumRepository extends ReadOnlyRepository<Album, Integer> {
     Iterable<Album> findAll();
     Optional<Album> findById(Integer id);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually have to put the curly braces on the url.

Try with this:

```
localhost:8080/demo/oneAlbum/1
```

Also, use an integer for that id instead of a string.